# Conditionally Populate Class Field in LINQ To Entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an EF class that looks like this:

```
public class Item
public string ItemId{ get; set; } 
public string NormalDescription { get; set; } 
public string LongDescription { get; set; } 
public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
.. <snip>
```

In addition, I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
public class ItemDTO
public string Id { get; set; } 
public string DisplayName { get; set; }
.. <snip>
```

Upon loading the data from the 'Item' class into the DTO, I need to conditionally set 'DisplayName' based on a configuration setting.  In other words, I'm looking for something similar to:

```
return _repo.GetAsQueryable<Item>()
    .Select(i=> new ItemDTO
    {
        Id = i.ItemId,
        DisplayName = (setting == 1) ? i.NormalDescription :
                      (setting == 2) ? i.LongDescription :
                      (setting == 3) ? i.ShortDescription :
                      String.Empty
    }
```

Of course, this results in some very inefficient SQL (using 'CASE' to evaluate each possible value) being sent to the database.  This is a performance issue as there's a TON of description fields on the Item.

That being said, is there a way to select ONLY the field that's required to populate the 'DisplayName' value?

In other words, instead of a query filled with 'CASE WHEN' logic, I'd like to ONLY retrieve one of the Description values based on my application configuration setting.

Comment: It will only get Id and DisplayName as it is now. Whats the issue?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, it populates Id and DisplayName, but it uses very inefficient SQL. In other words, it queries the database using a ton of 'CASE WHEN' logic.  I was hoping there was a deterministic way to populate the LINQ select projection..

Comment: `case when` is pretty efficient. What are your performance goals? Did you benchmark?

Comment: Your options are either the case statements or query all columns and do the mapping in memory or do a separate query for each case.

Comment: A more radical change would be to restructure your DB tables to have a Description table with a foreign key to the Item table and a description name and type.  Then your settings could match up with the type.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Unfortunately, due to the number of description columns (around 30), the performance is about the same as 'SELECT *' (note I also have 33 vendor columns that need to be handled the same way).  It's an annoying database design to say the least..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var repo = _repo.GetAsQueryable<Item>();

if (setting == 1)
{
    return repo.Select(i => new ItemDTO
    {
        Id = i.ItemId,
        DisplayName = i.NormalDescription
    });
}
if (setting == 2)
{
    return repo.Select(i => new ItemDTO
    {
        Id = i.ItemId,
        DisplayName = i.LongDescription
    });
}
if (setting == 3)
{
    return repo.Select(i => new ItemDTO
    {
        Id = i.ItemId,
        DisplayName = i.ShortDescription
    });
}
return repo.Select(i => new ItemDTO
{
    Id = i.ItemId,
    DisplayName = String.Empty
});
```

**EDIT**

You can create the expression dynamically as Slava Utesinov showed. If you do not want to build the whole expression, you can replace just the parts you want:

```
public class UniRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    readonly Func<Expression, Expression> replacement;

    UniRebinder(Func<Expression, Expression> replacement)
    {
        this.replacement = replacement;
    }

    public static Expression Replace(Expression exp, Func<Expression, Expression> replacement)
    {
        return new UniRebinder(replacement).Visit(exp);
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression p)
    {
        return base.Visit(replacement(p));
    }
}

Expression<Func<Item, ItemDTO>> ReplaceProperty(
    int setting, Expression<Func<Item, ItemDTO>> value)
{
    Func<MemberExpression, Expression> SettingSelector(int ss)
    {
        switch (ss)
        {
            case 1: return x => Expression.MakeMemberAccess(x.Expression, typeof(Item).GetProperty(nameof(Item.NormalDescription)));
            case 2: return x => Expression.MakeMemberAccess(x.Expression, typeof(Item).GetProperty(nameof(Item.LongDescription)));
            case 3: return x => Expression.MakeMemberAccess(x.Expression, typeof(Item).GetProperty(nameof(Item.ShortDescription)));
            default: return x => Expression.Constant(String.Empty);
        }
    }

    return (Expression<Func<Item, ItemDTO>>)UniRebinder.Replace(
        value,
        x =>
        {
            if (x is MemberExpression memberExpr
                && memberExpr.Member.Name == nameof(Item.NormalDescription))
            {
                return SettingSelector(setting)(memberExpr);
            }

            return x;
        });
}


private void Test()
{
    var repo = (new List<Item>() {
        new Item() {
            ItemId ="1",
            LongDescription = "longd1",
            NormalDescription = "normald1",
            ShortDescription = "shortd1" },
        new Item() {
            ItemId ="2",
            LongDescription = "longd2",
            NormalDescription = "normald2",
            ShortDescription = "shortd2" }
    }).AsQueryable();

    for (int selector = 1; selector < 5; ++selector)
    {
        var tst = repo.Select(ReplaceProperty(selector,
            i => new ItemDTO
            {
                Id = i.ItemId,
                DisplayName = i.NormalDescription
            })).ToList();


        Console.WriteLine(selector + ": " + string.Join(", ", tst.Select(x => x.DisplayName)));
        //Output:
        //1: normald1, normald2
        //2: longd1, longd2
        //3: shortd1, shortd2
        //4: , 
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but unfortunately, there's around 30 different description fields on the item..so I'd have to repeat the above for each and every setting...

Comment: @TelJanini You could just create the expression used by the `Select` in the if statements.  That could be useful if your actually query is more complex.

Comment: @juharr That sounds like exactly what I need, any helpful links to show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should create `lambda` `Expression` dynamically:

```
var typeOfItem = typeof(Item);
var argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeOfItem, "x");
var itemIdProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, "ItemId");

var properties = typeOfItem.GetProperties();
Expression descriptionProperty;
if (setting < properties.Count())            
    descriptionProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, properties[setting].Name);
else
    descriptionProperty = Expression.Constant(string.Empty);

var ItemDTOType = typeof(ItemDTO);

var newInstance = Expression.MemberInit(
    Expression.New(ItemDTOType),
    new List<MemberBinding>()
    {
        Expression.Bind(ItemDTOType.GetMember("Id")[0], itemIdProperty),
        Expression.Bind(ItemDTOType.GetMember("DisplayName")[0], descriptionProperty),
    }
);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, ItemDTO>>(newInstance, argParam);

return _repo.GetAsQueryable<Item>().Select(lambda);
```